# A few basic questions about Prolog

Tags: prolog

I am really basic in Prolog and just started to learn it.  Anyway I'm using Mac and downloaded SWI-Prolog/XPCE 6.3.12 for Mac. The software looks like CMD and Terminal.  So now I think I have to create a source file. The .pl format right?

Where should I save this file?
How to load it?
So can this be the source of my program? Is is correct?

```
edge(a,b).
edge(a,e).
edge(b,d).
edge(b,c).
edge(c,a).
edge(e,b).
```

Comment: This is valid Prolog; how close it is to what you want is hard to tell without knowing what that is.

Comment: @ScottHunter I copied it from a tutorial, so thats not a problem. but doesnt it need any heading or anything before/after the code?

Comment: @AlexJj: no, this is enough to be a valid Prolog program.

Comment: you can use the IDE. Try typing `?- emacs.` on console (without the prompt ?-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Save this file anywhere you want, call it (e.g.) `edges.pl`, fire up a Prolog interpreter in the same directory and type `[edges].` (including the period).

Comment: How can I open the Prolog interpreter in the same directory? It swill is located in /opt/local/bin

Comment: If a program is properly installed on a Unix or BSD system (like you Mac), the system knows where to look for it. You simply have to write its name on the command line. So you edit and save your source file (the one with the edges and with the .pl extension) in a directory, then you open a command line prompt (terminal) and go to that directory. At this point you type `swipl` and the interactive interpreter should start. And yes, the listing above is a complete program. You can load it by typing the name of the file inside brackets, without the .pl (so type `[edges].` not forgetting the dot)

Comment: And really ask someone around you to help you in person, it will be much faster with such basic issues.